# Prevent bootstrap alert from changing position of other elementts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I prevent the rest of my element from moving after dismiss of my alert message? This is what it looks like before dismissal.
[image: Before]

And this is what it looks like afterwards
[image]

If it isn't obvious. The form shifted up.

Currently my whole page is using flexbox like this.

```
display: "flex",
minHeight: "100vh",
alignItems: "center"
```

How do I go about remediying this?

Comment: Can you give us a working demo of the current state?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position of the `alert` class for relative positioning.

```
.alert {
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
}
```